# How to set up 403 error custom html page in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

i had already restrict the images and pdf from direct URL Like If anyone enter direct url of image `http://localhost/project/images/home.PNG`
Then It Will Be Redirect On 403 Page but i want to set new html for this error just like 404 so how can i do this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/project [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/project.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|pdf|png|gif|PNG)$ - [F]
```

This is How i restrict the images from folder please suggest me how to show custom html for 403 Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Applications/errors` folder create an `error_403.php` with your custom UI

OR

Just edit the `index.php` file in `Applications/errors` folder

Comment: oh..I Just create an error_403.php page with your custom UI in "\application\errors\" folder

Comment: OR

Just edit the index.php file in "Applications/errors" folder

Comment: in application/error/ there only four file named error_404.php,error_db.php,error_general.php,error_php.php and last is index.html that contains the directory access forbidden

Comment: yes.. You are getting error 403  right?  so the index.php file is getting called. you just check out the index.php file located in application/error folder. it is supposed to show "error 403 directory access forbidden". Edit that file if you need any customization.